# Extraction german verb conjugations from xml dump templates

Tags: dictionary, wiktionary

I would like to get a normalized list of German verb conjugations starting out withe the wiktionary XML dump.

I think I can manage to parse the XML dump, but I don't understand how wiktionary translates a Flexion template into a normalized display like for instance https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:lesen

which seems to be expanded from:

```
{{Deutsch Verb unregelmäßig|2=les|3=las|4=läs|5=gelesen|6=lies|7=-s|8=i|vp=ja|zp=nein|gerund=ja}}
```

Pointers to this normalization code would be hugely appreciated. I found a number of XML parsers for wiktionary on GitHub, but none seem to cover verb conjugations, and other question about wiktionary don't seem to cover this either.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I found some info on irregular verbs here: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Vorlage:Deutsch_Verb_unregelm%C3%A4%C3%9Fig

But I don't know if there is a complete set of templates with adequate documentation

Comment: More: https://github.com/zavsil/SAPA/blob/563fd3fe6645b86db9800b64ea922c96c3b9cb26/lib/CorrectorOrtografico/src/com/inet/jorthodictionaries/BookGenerator_de.java

Also, a writeup at https://home.uni-leipzig.de/horst-rothe/verbform.htm 

It would still be nice to have an authoritative piece of code in github etc.